# django many to many "through" table which inherits base model in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need to migrate saleor product models which is in django to fastapi using sqlalchemy orm. I am having hard time on many to many model part. In case of saleor's product model `AssignedProductAttribute` is a through model which itself inherits `BaseAssignedAttribute` abstract model which has another many to many fields. I mean the model related to product attributes look like this in django

```
class BaseAssignedAttribute(models.Model):
    assignment = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self.assignment.attribute

    @property
    def attribute_pk(self):
        return self.assignment.attribute_id


class Attribute(ModelWithMetadata):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    product_types = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductType,
        blank=True,
        related_name="product_attributes",
        through="AttributeProduct",
        through_fields=("attribute", "product_type"),
    )
    product_variant_types = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductType,
        blank=True,
        related_name="variant_attributes",
        through="AttributeVariant",
        through_fields=("attribute", "product_type"),
    )

    value_required = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
   

class AssignedProductAttributeValue(SortableModel):
    value = models.ForeignKey(
        "AttributeValue",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="productvalueassignment",
    )
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        "AssignedProductAttribute",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="productvalueassignment",
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("value", "assignment"),)
        ordering = ("sort_order", "pk")

    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        return self.assignment.productvalueassignment.all()


class AssignedProductAttribute(BaseAssignedAttribute):
    """Associate a product type attribute and selected values to a given product."""

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="attributes", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        "AttributeProduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="productassignments"
    )
    values = models.ManyToManyField(
        "AttributeValue",
        blank=True,
        related_name="productassignments",
        through=AssignedProductAttributeValue,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("product", "assignment"),)


class AttributeProduct(SortableModel):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        "Attribute", related_name="attributeproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="attributeproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assigned_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        blank=True,
        through=AssignedProductAttribute,
        through_fields=("assignment", "product"),
        related_name="attributesrelated",
    )

    objects = AssociatedAttributeQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("attribute", "product_type"),)
        ordering = ("sort_order", "pk")
```

I am struggling to migrate such model in sqlalchemy and this is what I have been able to so far

```
class BaseAssignedAttribute(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    assignment = None




class ProductType(Base, TimestampMixin):
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    # referencing a collection of products represented by the child
    products = relationship("Product", back_populates="product_type")
    attribute_products = relationship("AttributeProduct", back_populates="product_type")
    has_variants = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    is_shipping_required = Column(Boolean(), default=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        generate_slug(self, sluggable_column="title", *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title


class Product(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    # referencing the parent
    product_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product_type.id"))
    # to establish a bidirectional relationship(many to one) through relationship and back_ref
    product_type = relationship("ProductType", back_populates="products")
    collections = relationship(
        "Collection", secondary="ProductCollection", back_populates="product"
    )
    attribute_products = relationship(
        "AttributeProduct",
        secondary="AssignedProductAttribute",
        back_populates="assigned_products",
    )


class Attribute(Base):
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    # type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=AttributeType.CHOICES)
    # product_types = relationship()
    # product_variant_types = relationship()
    value_required = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    attribute_values = relationship("AttributeValue", back_populates="attribute")
    attribute_products = relationship("AttributeProduct", back_populates="attribute")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        generate_slug(self, sluggable_column="title", *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<Atribute {self.title}>"


class AttributeValue(Base):
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    attribute_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attribute.id"))
    attribute = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="attribute_values")
    assigned_product_attribute_values = relationship(
        "AssignedProductAttributeValue", back_populates="attribute_value"
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        generate_slug(self, sluggable_column="title", *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<AttributeValue {self.title}>"


class AssignedProductAttributeValue(Base):
    attribute_value_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attribute_value.id"))
    attribute_value = relationship(
        "AttributeValue", back_populates="assigned_product_attribute_values"
    )


class AssignedProductAttribute(BaseAssignedAttribute):
    """Associate a product type attribute and selected values to a given product."""

    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product.id"))
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="assigned_product_attributes")
    attribute_product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attribute_product.id"))


class AttributeProduct(Base):
    attribute_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attribute.id"))
    attribute = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="attribute_products")
    product_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product_type.id"))
    product_type = relationship("ProductType", back_populates="attribute_products")
    assigned_products = relationship(
        "Product",
        secondary="AssignedProductAttribute",
        back_populates="attribute_products",
    )
```

Actually, I am also confused wherever many-to-many field is used. I am not sure if I can ask multiple question so my major concern is to know about the relationship between `AssignedProductAttributeValue`, `AssignedProductAttribute` and `AttributeProduct`.